# theoretically exercise on derivatives

Tags: functions, derivatives

How can I prove for a function $f$ which has a derivative at $x_0$ the followings:

1. $$\lim_{h\to 0}{\frac{f(x_0-h)-f(x_0)}{h}}=-f'(x_0)$$
2. $$\lim_{h\to 0}{\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0-h)}{h}}=2f'(x_0)$$

I suspect that I need to use the definition:
$$f'(x_0)=\lim_{h\to 0}{\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}}$$
but I am a little bit confused on how exactly I will use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $u=-h$

1. $$\lim_{u\to 0}{\frac{f(x_0+u)-f(x_0)}{-u}}=-f'(x_0)$$

$$\lim_{h\to 0}{\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0-h)}{h}}={\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)+f(x_0)-f(x_0-h)}{h}}={\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}}- {\frac{f(x_0-h)-f(x_0)}{h}}=2f'(x_0).$$

Answer (score 1):

2) follows very easily from 1) and the definition of the derivative.

Notice that 
$$\begin{align}\dfrac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0-h)}{h}&= \dfrac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)+f(x_0)-f(x_0-h)}{h} \\
&= \dfrac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0) -[f(x_0-h)-f(x_0)]}{h} \\
&= \dfrac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}-\dfrac{f(x_0-h)-f(x_0)}{h}\text{.}
\end{align}$$
Now take the limit as $h \to 0$ on both sides.